# SSL Certification Status Failing with Heroku

Tags: ssl, heroku

I purchased my domain name with GoDaddy and have my site hosted on Heroku. I added an SSL cert via `heroku certs:auto:enable` and when I check the status with `heroku certs:auto` it shows www.mydomainname.com having a status as 'ok', however, the naked route mydomainname.com is failing. In the DNS section in GoDaddy, I have the following for the cname:

Host: www
Points to: www.mydomainname.com.herokudns.com
TTL: 1/2

Additionally, the mydomainname.com is forwarded on Godaddy.

Is the problem because it's being forwarded?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue as you. If you find the solution please do post!

Comment: @justin I'll definitely let you know if I find a solution.